# Django no such table: project_forum?

Tags: django

So I'm trying to make a forum with django, but I keep getting an operational error no such table: project_forum. My code:

list.html (/visdjango/visdjango/templates/list.html)

```
<!-- Forums  -->
<div id="list">
<table border="0" cellpadding="4" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Posts</td>
    <td>Last post</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

{% for forum in forums %}
<tr>
    <td {% if forloop.last %}class="last"{% endif %}>
    <div class="title"> <a href="{% url forum.views.forum forum.pk %}">{{ forum.title }}</a>
        </div></td>
    <td {% if forloop.last %}class="last"{% endif %}>{{ forum.num_posts }}</td>
    <td {% if forloop.last %}class="last"{% endif %}>
        {{ forum.last_post.short|linebreaksbr }}</td>
    <td {% if forloop.last %}class="last"{% endif %}>
        <a class="button" href="{% url forum.views.forum forum.pk %}">VIEW</a>
    </td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

Then views.py (visdjango/project/views.py)

```
def forum(request, pk):
    return render_to_response('template/forum.html', {
        'forums': Forum.objects.all()
        })
```

models.py (visdjango/project/models.py)

```
class Forum(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title+" - "+self.created

    def num_posts(self):
        return sum([t.num_posts() for t in self.thread_set.all()])

    def last_post(self):
        if self.thread_set.count():
            last = None
            for t in self.thread_set.all():
                l = t.last_post()
                if l:
                    if not last: last = l
                    elif l.created > last.created: last = l
            return last
```

Finally, in settings.py (visdjango/visdjango/setttings.py)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Sorry for long post, thanks

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Have you run syncdb since you create the forum model?

Comment: Your table name is project_forum?

Comment: did you add forum app to settings?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding so quickly, I figured out that my problem was that I forgot to add the folder containing my models (project) to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

Comment: Don't use 1.8, it is still a work in progress. Use the brand new 1.7 release.